# I am making a creature with sloth like claws and need to know how it would be used for climbing trees and walking

Tags: biology, creature-design, xenobiology, environment, animal-locomotion

[image: enter preformatted text here]

My question is about my creatures.So in my world i have these creatures that have bladed claws on each leg think like a sloths claws they have 6 limbs in total two strong arms to move from tree to tree like a monkey. they also have a monkey like torso and 2 legs on either side of its pelvis to climb trees like how a cocunout crab climbs trees now im just wondering on how it would walk on the ground i was thinking about how spiders or like crabs walk on their legs would be similar but the claws are a little curved and i feel like it wouldnt work if it was trying to walk on land. so is there a way for me to keep the claws and have it walk on land one of the ideas i had was its body would be like a pryaing mantis when its standing on the ground could this work or would i need to change some things also the claws are used for griping/digging into prey when they jump form their trees to fall onto their food to kill it and should be able to walk. and if this helps they have a simillar body plan to that of arthropods and the world has more oxygen i though this would help because arthropods take a lot of oxygen and can get big and oxygen is more deleverd to the musscles.

Comment: You know, periods are a beautiful thing

Comment: sorry i forgot i didnt even notice lol

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding! Please take the [tour] and read the [help], and if you’re confused about the rules feel free to ask in [meta] or [chat]

Comment: @NuclearWill I know at least one recent recipient of a hysterectomy who very strongly disagreed on that subject...

Comment: @StarfishPrime "periods are a beautiful thing _for/in others_" Better now? ;)

Answer (score 2):

## New Section

This creature, based on the image, seems to have a rather ape-like anatomy, especially at the limbs. This indicates to me that an ape-like method of locomotion would be most suitable

There are some tweaks specific to this creature: Specifically, it would need to use all four hindlimbs when walking upright, and these hindlimbs would need to have the claws folded up, as in knuckle-walkers' forefeet. Their foreclaws would also have to be folded up while walking on them. They also would rarely walk upright, due to the issues of balance, and should only do it when needing to run or grab at prey

---

*PREVIOUS VERSION*

### For the Forelimbs

Consider the anteaters: They are the closest living relatives of the sloth, and this can be quite evident in their claw anatomy. Even with the simian and arthropodal anatomy, the anteater's knuckle-walking solution seems like a wonderful solution. This is further backed up by the pangolins and chalicotheres, which, though not that related, have similar claws, and also walk on their knuckles

There are alternatives: For example, many pangolins can walk or stand bipedally with the forelimbs completely off the ground, which is an execellent way to protect the claws

### For the Other Limbs

A coconut crab's legs at the pelvis seems like an excellent feature for this species, especially if you decide to have them walk with their forelegs off the ground. Having a pair of legs that point sharply forwards, like in a coconut crab, would be very good for balance. It's not hard to imagine this animal standing quadrupedally with the coconut crab feet being extended to be directly under the folded arms

Comment: the troble is they only have one claw on each limb i forgot to metion that its just one big claw on each leg and forarm

Comment: @ErikSanchez My solutions will still work with one claw per foot

Comment: is there a way for me to deliver pictures here  so i can at least show a refrence becuase i dont think this is enough but im not saying the informating isnt helpful i quiet enjoyed it

Comment: @ErikSanchez You can add pictures to your question with the image option in the editor, which would be the box 4th along in the second set of options in the editor's top ribbon

Comment: i added the picture hope this helps

Comment: @ErikSanchez I added a new section to my answer, based on the image you added