# I need help with aquatic arthropods

Tags: evolution, aliens, worldbuilding-process, sea-creatures, adaptability

How would an [arthropod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod) (invertebrate animals with an exoskeleton)replace and or evolve into a fish-like animal (using terrestrial fish as an example)the question is how would they recrate a ocean environment and have a fish like body

Please note these creatures just evolved from a ancestor with similar features as a arthropod but you can use real arthropods if its for research.

Comment: Sanchez the regulars here are a bunch of grumpy old folks.  We like sentences and capitalization and punctuation like they used to have back in the 2010s.    It is good practice for you too.   You have potential.  If you are smart enough to come up with schemes like this you are smart enough to write (and spellcheck) paragraphs for other smart people to read.   Write a paragraph about your beast that makes people who love alien beasts want to get involved.   I love a weird alien critter more than most but when I see a block of lame text like this I don't want to play.

Comment: duely noted.but t warn you im not good at spelling no matter how hard i try

Comment: Duely noted.i shall try my best but for the love of my life i just can`t spell sometimes

Comment: That's alright! Do your very best to present yourself positively when you write questions in here (and indeed everywhere else in your online life, because in the real world, you only set yourself up for failure by not presenting a well written & reasonably well spelled piece of communication). After you write a question (or answer) do your best to review it and edit it. After you give editing a try or two, someone else will come along and clean up the damage! Keep in mind: your communications skill don't just reflect on you; they also reflect on the community and from now into the future.

Comment: Apart from spelling & punctuation: would you be so kind as to add a link to a previous query in which you describe your world? I have no idea what the "world with the claw thing" refers to!

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/215607/making-a-creature-with-sloth-like-claws-for-climbing-trees-and-walking hope this helps and takes you where you need to go i just hope someone answers this question about the water insects.

Comment: Arthropods have exoskeleton. Sharks fish etc have internal skeleton. One can presumably evolve into the other - but then arthropods would no longer be arthropods.

Comment: yeah i came into that problem a bit so they have similar features basicly is what im trying to say they are more mimic arthropods or similar to then ``true``arthropods but if i do chose true arthropods then how would it adapt for life in the sea.

Comment: I couldn't stand it, I had to edit your post. I understand your challenges, but if I had to guess, you're typing on your phone. Please understand, the style of writing you presented is called "train of thought" and it's very uncomfortable to read. Having said that, I'm inclined to vote to close your question. I'm not a fan of questions that ask, "how could X evolve?" That's nearly impossible to answer on Earth, but you're asking us to explain it on your fictional world. Can you explain why you need this explanation? What are you expecting? (\*continued\*)

Comment: ... It's beyond the scope of this site to provide a change-by-change description of how one creature can become another. Especially when, given enough time, basically anything can evolve into anything. Are you really asking for a million-year-history of your creature in an environment we know nothing about? (Asking us to assume that it's like Earth doesn't fly with me, Real World questions are supposed to have a worldbuilding context.) So, what's the real problem you're trying to solve? Why are you asking this question?

Comment: Ok im typing on a chromebook not a phone and yes my spelling isn`t the greatest.and what im expecting is how they would look its just ideas ive had recently and i was just looking for a way to desing them without being to alien ironic right.i guess i didnt think the whole question through,basically how to would a creature adapt(is that the right word)to a aquatic environment if they had similar characteristics as arthropods such as spider,crabs,insects etc.they are also not arthropods they are there own species they just look like them.

Comment: Aquatic arthropods already exist. It's really unclear what your actual question is.

Comment: i meant as fish having a fish body type no crabs,lobsters or shrimp

Answer (score 10):

**1:  Shrimp compete with fish.**

https://apps-nefsc.fisheries.noaa.gov/rcb/photogallery/shrimp.html

[image: shrimp]

Here is an example of an arthropod body plan evolved to be a match with fish.  Maybe not esoteric enough for your needs but the real deal.

---

2:  **Swimming bug x armored fish.**

But let us get more awesome.  We will start with the most water adapted insect I can think of: the Belostoma water bug.

[image: water bub]

https://bugguide.net/node/view/626889/bgimage

And we will take a page from the playbook of the Devonian armorer fishes like Dunkles here.

[image: dunks]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkleosteus

Of course the armor is not bony plates but exoskeleton.

The result: a swimming bug with grabbing appendages, body armor and a wicked bite.  These things would be too heavily armored to fly but the shrimp are ok with that.

Drawing to come, I hope!

Comment: thanks for the informating when i do draw them ill make sure to send them here

Comment: Does a crustacean [looking like sushi](https://www.livescience.com/sushi-isopod-fukushima-aquarium) count? I mean... technically the central piece of sushi is fish.

Comment: i would say so in my honnest opinoin

Answer (score 6):

[image: evhjejrebk]

This is a crustacean from the genus *Triops*. It isn't quite fish-like at the moment but it does look quite similar to some ancient armored fishes.

[image]

*Bothriolepis*

[image]

*Cephalaspis*

All of those little tendrils and feathery protrusions and legs could be simplified into paddle-like fins.

[image]

This is a pentastomid, or a "tongue worm." It may look like some kind of flatworm but it is actually a parasitic crustacean. It doesn't look like a traditional fish but it could pass for an eel or perhaps a ray-like fish if the flaps on the side were more pronounced.

BTW Jupiter already has a moon called Europa.

Comment: thank you for the information also i forgot the name of my planet looked through and found it its name is actualy chlorea